# Solve $A_n=A_{n-1}+\lfloor \sqrt{A_{n-1}}\rfloor$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the recurrence:

$A_0=1$

$A_n=A_{n-1}+\lfloor \sqrt{A_{n-1}}\rfloor,\text{ for } n > 0$

Its obvious that

$A_n=m^2 \implies A_{n+1}=m^2+m$

however my book's solution states that the key insight is to realize:

$A_n=m^2 \implies A_{n+2k+1}=(m+k)^2+m-k\text{, for }0 \le k \le m$

and

$A_n=m^2 \implies A_{n+2k+2}=(m+k)^2+2m\text{, for }0 \le k \le m$

What method or line of thinking would have lead me to this?

This is exercise 3.28 from [Concrete Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use $r(x) = \lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor$ throughout.

**Warm Up** Here's some stuff we'll use freely in the next section. It's motivated by the next section though.

What's the floor of the square root of $m^2+7m+5$? You can read it off this table:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
m+k & m^2 + 2km + k^2 \\ \hline
m+1 & m^2 + 2m + 1 \\
m+2 & m^2 + 4m + 4 \\
m+3 & m^2 + 6m + 9 \\
m+4 & m^2 + 8m + 16 \\
m+5 & m^2 + 10m + 25 \\
m+6 & m^2 + 12m + 36 \\
m+7 & m^2 + 14m + 49 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

It must be $m+3$.. but we do *need* $2k < m$ to use this table. It's easy to find counterexamples (e.g. $r(3^2+7\cdot 3+5)=5$).

---

Using this we can push your idea of starting with a generic $A_n = m^2$ much further and see the recurrence:

$$\begin{array}{|l|l|} \hline
A_n & r(A_n) \\ \hline
m^2 & m \\
m^2 + m & m \\
m^2 + 2m & m \\
m^2 + 3m & m + 1 \\
m^2 + 4m + 1 & m + 1 \\
m^2 + 5m + 2 & m + 2 \\
m^2 + 6m + 4 & m + 2 \\
m^2 + 8m + 6 & m + 3 \\
\end{array}$$

of course with the same caveat as before.

To try to formulate the pattern in this table (in order to prove it by induction) we get exactly the *key insight* you mentioned.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you see both equalities: $(m+k)^2+m-k+(m+k)=(m+k)^2+2m$  and $(m+k)^2+2m+(m+k)=(m+(k+1))^2+m-(k+1)$